# Read from stdin AND forward it to a subprocess in Python

Tags: python, stream, subprocess, stdin

I'm writing a wrapper script for a program that optionally accepts input from STDIN. My script needs to process each line of the file, but it also needs to forward STDIN to the program it is wrapping. In minimalist form, this looks something like this:

```
import subprocess
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
    # Do something with each line
    pass

subprocess.call(['cat'])
```

Note that I'm not actually trying to wrap `cat`, it just serves as an example to demonstrate whether or not STDIN is being forwarded properly.

With the example above, if I comment out the for-loop, it works properly. But if I run it with the for-loop, nothing gets forwarded because I've already read to the end of STDIN. I can't `seek(0)` to the start of the file because you can't seek on streams.

One possible solution is to read the entire file into memory:

```
import subprocess
import sys

lines = sys.stdin.readlines()
for line in lines:
    # Do something with each line
    pass

p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
p.communicate(''.join(lines))
```

which works, but isn't very memory efficient. Can anyone think of a better solution? Perhaps a way to split or copy the stream?

Additional Constraints:

1. The subprocess can only be called once. So I can't read a line at a time, process it, and forward it to the subprocess.
2. The solution must work in Python 2.6

Comment: If I understand this correctly, you want to essentially forward data from `stdin` to the `stdin` of the subprocess?

Comment: Yes, but if all I wanted to do was forward `stdin` to the subprocess, `subprocess.call(['cat'])` would be all I would need. I want to forward `stdin` AND be able to read and process it.

Comment: It's hard to tell whether I'm understanding your question correctly.  Start with: `python -c $'import subprocess;\nimport sys;\np = subprocess.Popen(["cat", "-n"], stdin=subprocess.PIPE);\nfor line in iter(sys.stdin.readline,""): p.stdin.write(line)'`   (put it in a normal .py file, I'm just putting it on one line so I can get it in this comment).  Then  insert `do_something_else_with(line)` before the `p.stdin.write(line)`.   Your constraint #1 sounds like this won't work for you for some reason, but I don't understand why not.  Can you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

Does this work for you?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2
import subprocess
import sys

p = subprocess.Popen(['cat'], stdin = subprocess.PIPE)

line = sys.stdin.readline()

####################
# Insert work here #
####################

line = line.upper()

####################

p.communicate(line)
```

Example:

```
$ echo "hello world" | ./wrapper.py 
HELLO WORLD
```

Comment: There are two problems with this solution:

1. It only forwards the first line of stdin, not every line. You would need to use `readlines` (plural) and join them when communicating them to the subprocess.

2. This is the same solution I already presented, jumbled around a bit. It has the flaw that it reads the entire file into memory. I'm looking for a more memory efficient solution (if one exists).

Comment: Thinking out loud here. What if the code after the subprocess was inside a while loop continuously reading in a single line, processing it and then communicating it? Would that not be a streaming like approach similar to what you're looking for?

Comment: See Additional Constraints: #1.

Comment: Yea, the subprocess would be called once, but you'd be streaming the lines to it as the script gets them.