# Git commit Vim in personal project

Tags: python, vim, scripting

I am making a small python script that should prompt the user for input. I like how `git commit` prompts the user with a vim prompt, and then uses this prompt to get the commit message.

Is it possible to implement this behavior in python?

I cannot use input(or stdin in general)

Comment: If you can't use stdin then can whatever program you launch use it? Effectivly when you use subprocess, you can forward std in to the stdin of the subprocess, which makes it interactive. IIRC what git does is tell vim to open with a save file name of some temp file, then read that file after vim has quit. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40935208/read-from-stdin-and-forward-it-to-a-subprocess-in-python ?

Comment: You can see how git actually launches external editor here: https://github.com/git/git/blob/936d1b989416a95f593bf81ccae8ac62cd83f279/editor.c#L37

Comment: Thanks, i'll look into it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very simple: put initial text into a temporary file, start an editor (determined by the well-known environment variables with fallback to `vi`), wait the editor to finish and get the content of the temp file.

See an example at https://chase-seibert.github.io/blog/2012/10/31/python-fork-exec-vim-raw-input.html

```
import tempfile
import subprocess
import os

def raw_input_editor(default=None, editor=None):
    ''' like the built-in raw_input(), except that it uses a visual
    text editor for ease of editing. Unline raw_input() it can also
    take a default value. '''
    with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode='r+') as tmpfile:
        if default:
            tmpfile.write(default)
            tmpfile.flush()
        subprocess.check_call([editor or get_editor(), tmpfile.name])
        tmpfile.seek(0)
        return tmpfile.read().strip()

def get_editor():
    return (os.environ.get('VISUAL')
        or os.environ.get('EDITOR')
        or 'vi')
```